# why does jasper only return 1 when trying to sum two total columns

Tags: jasper-reports

When I only put `<![CDATA[$V{activated1}/$V{total1}+1]]>` i get a value of 1

When I only put `<![CDATA[$V{activated1}]]>` i get a value of 496
When I only put `<![CDATA[$V{total1}]]>` i get a value of 7796
When I only put `<![CDATA[$V{activated1}/$V{total1}]]>` i get a value of 0

Why does the division not work. I want to achieve this in the end

`<![CDATA[$V{activated1}/$V{total1} * 100]]>` to get the percentage value of the column totals

Is there any reason for this

Comment: it's probably doing integer division. 496/7796 = 0.06... which rounds down to `0`.

Comment: Is it possible to cast the values to real beforehand?

Comment: maybe `.divide()`? No idea. never used jasper before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast it into `BigDecimal` and use the *.divide()* function

Here is an example:
intV1 and intV2 are `Integer` variables.

```
new BigDecimal($V{intV1}).divide(  new BigDecimal($V{intV2} ) )
```